# fetch mysql information based on column value

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to run a mysql $query and specify and order by the value within a column. so if you have a table with column:name, and there are 2 people with the name 'john' but the first john has 'id':10  and the second john has 'id':20. I want to echo the first john(10) first. so something like:

```
  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT firstname FROM users 
                   WHERE email='$email' 
                   AND id='(*smallest value*)'");

  while($info = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
  echo $info['firstname']
```

Comment: I believe you need to use the `order by` clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT firstname FROM users WHERE email='$email' order by id asc limit 1`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT firstname FROM users WHERE email='$email' order by id asc limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT firstname FROM users 
               WHERE email='$email' 
               ORDER BY id ASC");
```

will give you the John(10) before the John(20).

```
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT firstname FROM users 
               WHERE email='$email' 
               ORDER BY id ASC
               LIMIT 1");
```

will give you only John(10).